# Optimizing find on sorted list

Tags: recursion, optimization, language-agnostic, divide-and-conquer

I came across a problem where we get a sorted list of numbers and at some point the numbers in the list start repeating,
something like `0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,8,8`, we need to retrieve the position where the repetition started.

Below is the approach I've taken...

```js
function find(arr) {  
  let max = arr.length-1
  let min = 0
  do {
    let iter = Math.round((min + max) / 2)
    if (arr[max] == arr[iter])
      max = iter
    else
      min = iter
  } while (min + 1 < max)
  return max
}

arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,8,8]
console.log(find(arr))

arr = [0,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2]
console.log(find(arr))

arr = [0,2,4,6,8,10,10]
console.log(find(arr))
```

Probably there is a recursive way, but I could not figure it out
Is there a more efficient way to solve this?

Comment: you have lists or arrays ? and is it guaranteed, that only last element is repeating?

Comment: @bobra array, and yes safe to assume that only last element is repeating ... but if there are other repeats we can ignore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As bobra and Raymond Chen indicated, you can't do better than O(log n).  However, you had also asked about a recursive solution.  Here you go:

```js
function find(arr, min_idx = 0, max_idx = arr.length - 1) {
  if (min_idx >= max_idx)
    return max_idx 
  let guess = Math.floor((min_idx + max_idx) / 2)
  if (arr[guess] == arr[max_idx])
    return  find(arr, min_idx, guess)  
  return find(arr, guess + 1, max_idx)
}

let arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,8,8]
console.log(find(arr))

arr = [0,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2]
console.log(find(arr))

arr = [2,4,6,8,10,10]
console.log(find(arr))

arr = [10,10,10]
console.log(find(arr))
```

Note that this also fixes a bug in your implementation.  I've added a test case where yours gave the wrong answer when the first element was equal to the max.

Comment: That's the ticket, ye I knew that we really can't do better than logarithmic time, but efficiency is not only about BigO there are benefits of recursive algorithms, Divide-and-conquer is really good for execution in multi-processor

Answer (score 0):

I realized that all cases are:

- sequential only one repeats
- do not repeat at first element
- first element is always 0

Some concrete examples

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,8,8]
[0,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2]
[0,2,4,6,8,8,8,8,8,8,8]
[0,3,6,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9]
```

best solution was with just 2 observations `(last/second)` element, linear time

Answer (score -1):

your solution has `O(log N)` complexity. it seems there is no faster alghorithm than binary search here. so your solution is ok

Comment: Since there are n possible answers, you can't do better than log n. (An adversarial argument shows that any algorithm with lower complexity can be fooled.)